# Is it possible to trace the delegation path for a DNS lookup?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to determine why a [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) host check is failing (hostnames and IPs have been changed to protect the guilty):

```
: jmglov@laurana; host www.foo.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

: jmglov@laurana; for ns in `grep -o '\([0-9]\+[.]\)\{3\}[0-9]\+$' /etc/resolv.conf`; do ping -qc 1 $ns; done
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.911/10.911/10.911/0.000 ms
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.241/0.241/0.241/0.000 ms
```

So I know that my nameservers are reachable, meaning that some nameserver along the delegation path to the authoritative nameserver for my host is not responding. Is there an easy way to determine which nameserver this is (basically a *traceroute* for DNS)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Does this do the job for you?

```
dig +trace google.com
```

From the man page:

> **+[no]trace**
>          Toggle tracing of the delegation path from the root name
>   servers for the name being looked up.
>   Tracing is disabled by default. When
>   tracing is enabled, dig makes
>   iterative queries to resolve
>          the name being looked up. It will follow referrals from the root
>   servers, showing the answer from each
>   server that was used to resolve the
>   lookup.

Comment: That works a charm!

Comment: https://www.digwebinterface.com/ is really useful for this

Answer (score 32):

For **Windows** you can **trace your dns query** with

```
nslookup -debug google.at
```

You can also **trace it online** (of couse from another host) on http://www.simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx

Comment: `nslookup` just like `dig` works also under Mac OS X terminal.

Comment: This does not give the full details that I was looking for.  I have my router set to use Google's DNS and I was trying to confirm that it is actually doing that and not using my ISPs DNS.  If I perfrom an `nslookup` from the command prompt it tells me that the answer to my lookup came from 192.168.1.1, it's leaving out the intermediate steps.  A `dig` from my linux box provides more detail, including showing 8.8.8.8 in the chain.  Is there a way to do this via Windows?

Comment: This does not do the same as "dig +trace google.com" in a Linux or macOS system. It still does a recursive query to your local DNS instead of querying directly every nameserver in the trace.